# Check the presence of an item in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, member

To complete an exercise, I need to check if an element is in a list or not. I know that there is the function `member` in lisp, but our instructor is very strict and doesn't let us use things that haven't yet been covered in the course.

What would be a way to check if an atom is in a list by using only `cond`, `nil`, `car`, `not`, `cdr`, `+`, `equal`, `defun`?

---

Edit:
After Doseke's comment; here is an attempt:

```
(defun presence (list item)
   (cond
      ((atom list) nil)
      ((equal (car list) item) t)
      ((consp list) (presence (cdr list) item))
      (t nil)
      )
   )
```

**edit**: I changed the title to make it match with my actual question

Comment: Is it OK to use recursion and check if item equals to car?

Comment: @Doseke: Yes, I think so

Comment: `atom`, `consp` and `t` are not part of your “using only” list.

Comment: The "attempt" seems to be successful. You can self-answer if you want.

Comment: The question disagrees with its headline, which says you must return the same results as member. member returns the cons cell of which the value you seek is the car. But your question text says "check if...", which demands only a boolean. If you need to return the cons cell as does member, you have some work remaining! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are limited in used features, it could be something like this, i guess:

```
(defun member-2 (x xs)
  (cond ((not xs) nil)
        ((equal x (car xs)) xs)
        (t (member-2 x (cdr xs)))))
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, istead of using NOT, it would be better  to use ENDP as it communicates intent better. Or at least NULL

Comment: It is. I just used the constraints from the op's question. It includes ‘not‘ but doesn't include null )